# PHP Replace string allow only a-z A-Z 0-9 _ and . (dot)

Tags: php

I am working on registration and I need to check if username is valid a-z A-Z 0-9 _ and . (dot). How to do this in PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: what you want exactely in html form or in php side

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp it should help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/^[\w\.]+$/', $username)) {
     echo 'Username is valid';
}
```

**\w** - matches [a-zA-Z0-9_]+

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to do that.

here is an example :

```
if(preg_match($pattern,$value)) { 


}
```